# Is it possible to unit test BundleConfig in MVC4?

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-optimization, bundling-and-minification

As far as I can tell, the answer is no. The issue I'm seeing comes from the `Include(params string[])` method in the `System.Web.Optimization.Bundle` class. Internally this invokes `System.Web.Optimization.IncludeDirectory(string, string, bool)`, which in turn uses this code:

```
DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(
    HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(directoryVirtualPath));
```

While it is possible to set `HttpContext.Current` during a unit test, I can't figure out how to make its `.Server.MapPath(string directoryVirtualPath)` return a non-null string. Since the `DirectoryInfo(string)` constructor throws an exception when passed a null argument, such a test will always fail.

What is the .NET team's recommendation for this? Do we have to unit test bundling configurations as part of integration tests or user acceptance tests?

Comment: Really? Am I going to have to start a bounty on this one too???

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have some good news for you, for RTM we added a new static property on `BundleTable` to enable more unit tests:

```
public static Func<string, string> MapPathMethod;
```

**Edit** Updated with a test virtual path provider:

So you can do something like this:

```
public class TestVirtualPathProvider : VirtualPathProvider {

    private string NormalizeVirtualPath(string virtualPath, bool isDirectory = false) {
        if (!virtualPath.StartsWith("~")) {
            virtualPath = "~" + virtualPath;
        }
        virtualPath = virtualPath.Replace('\\', '/');
        // Normalize directories to always have an ending "/"
        if (isDirectory && !virtualPath.EndsWith("/")) {
            return virtualPath + "/";
        }
        return virtualPath;
    }

    // Files on disk (virtualPath -> file)
    private Dictionary<string, VirtualFile> _fileMap = new Dictionary<string, VirtualFile>();
    private Dictionary<string, VirtualFile> FileMap {
        get { return _fileMap; }
    }

    public void AddFile(VirtualFile file) {
        FileMap[NormalizeVirtualPath(file.VirtualPath)] = file;
    }

    private Dictionary<string, VirtualDirectory> _directoryMap = new Dictionary<string, VirtualDirectory>();
    private Dictionary<string, VirtualDirectory> DirectoryMap {
        get { return _directoryMap; }
    }

    public void AddDirectory(VirtualDirectory dir) {
        DirectoryMap[NormalizeVirtualPath(dir.VirtualPath, isDirectory: true)] = dir;
    }

    public override bool FileExists(string virtualPath) {
        return FileMap.ContainsKey(NormalizeVirtualPath(virtualPath));
    }

    public override bool DirectoryExists(string virtualDir) {
        return DirectoryMap.ContainsKey(NormalizeVirtualPath(virtualDir, isDirectory: true));
    }

    public override VirtualFile GetFile(string virtualPath) {
        return FileMap[NormalizeVirtualPath(virtualPath)];
    }

    public override VirtualDirectory GetDirectory(string virtualDir) {
        return DirectoryMap[NormalizeVirtualPath(virtualDir, isDirectory: true)];
    }

    internal class TestVirtualFile : VirtualFile {
        public TestVirtualFile(string virtualPath, string contents)
            : base(virtualPath) {
            Contents = contents;
        }

        public string Contents { get; set; }

        public override Stream Open() {
            return new MemoryStream(UTF8Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Contents));
        }
    }

    internal class TestVirtualDirectory : VirtualDirectory {
        public TestVirtualDirectory(string virtualPath)
            : base(virtualPath) {
        }

        public List<VirtualFile> _directoryFiles = new List<VirtualFile>();
        public List<VirtualFile> DirectoryFiles {
            get {
                return _directoryFiles;
            }
        }

        public List<VirtualDirectory> _subDirs = new List<VirtualDirectory>();
        public List<VirtualDirectory> SubDirectories {
            get {
                return _subDirs;
            }
        }

        public override IEnumerable Files {
            get {
                return DirectoryFiles;
            }
        }

        public override IEnumerable Children {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public override IEnumerable Directories {
            get { 
                return SubDirectories;
            }
        }
    }
```

And then write a unit test using that like so:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void StyleBundleCustomVPPIncludeVersionSelectsTest() {
        //Setup the vpp to contain the files/directories
        TestVirtualPathProvider vpp = new TestVirtualPathProvider();
        var directory = new TestVirtualPathProvider.TestVirtualDirectory("/dir/");
        directory.DirectoryFiles.Add(new TestVirtualPathProvider.TestVirtualFile("/dir/style1.0.css", "correct"));
        directory.DirectoryFiles.Add(new TestVirtualPathProvider.TestVirtualFile("/dir/style.css", "wrong"));
        vpp.AddDirectory(directory);

        // Setup the bundle
        ScriptBundle bundle = new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/test");
        bundle.Items.VirtualPathProvider = vpp;
        bundle.Include("~/dir/style{version}.css");

        // Verify the bundle repsonse
        BundleContext context = SetupContext(bundle, vpp);
        BundleResponse response = bundle.GetBundleResponse(context);
        Assert.AreEqual(@"correct", response.Content);
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this workaround is no longer possible in the latest version because the MapPathMethod has been removed. Can you advise on an alternative strategy (possibly using a VirtualPathProvider)?

Comment: Looks like it changed again, there's no Items property in bundle anymore.

Comment: You can set the VPP on the BundleTable instead, bundle.Items is internal.

Comment: @HaoKung, I tried following your suggestions about unit testing the bundle but whenever I try to enumerate the bundle files, I always get zero count. Can you have a look at my question please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25930610/how-to-unit-test-asp-net-bundles

Comment: I got this sample to work for me but if I remove the {version} wildcard and update the virtual file to style.css instead of style1.0.css it doesn't work.  I tried to step through the mock classes but I think it's the framework that does the wildcard matching.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

In .Net 4.5 things have slightly changed.  Here is a working version of the approved answer updated to accommodate these changes (I am using Autofac).  Note the "GenerateBundleResponse" instead of "GetBundleResponse":

```
    [Fact]
    public void StyleBundleIncludesVersion()
    {
        //Setup the vpp to contain the files/directories
        var vpp = new TestVirtualPathProvider();
        var directory = new TestVirtualPathProvider.TestVirtualDirectory("/dir/");
        directory.DirectoryFiles.Add(new TestVirtualPathProvider.TestVirtualFile("/dir/style1.0.css", "correct"));
        directory.DirectoryFiles.Add(new TestVirtualPathProvider.TestVirtualFile("/dir/style.css", "wrong"));
        vpp.AddDirectory(directory);

        // Setup the bundle
        var bundleCollection = new BundleCollection();
        var bundle = new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/test");
        BundleTable.VirtualPathProvider = vpp;
        bundle.Include("~/dir/style{version}.css");
        bundleCollection.Add(bundle);
        var mockHttpContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();

        // Verify the bundle repsonse
        var context = new BundleContext(mockHttpContext.Object, bundleCollection, vpp.ToString());
        var response = bundle.GenerateBundleResponse(context);
        Assert.Equal(@"correct", response.Content);
    }
```